# Read an enum from a header file in a .cpp file (C++)

Tags: c++, object, enums

First off, sorry for my English, I'm a French Canadian.

I have a homework to do: a solitaire game. The problem is that I'm stuck at the obligatory enum step. I need to use an enum for my cards.

Here's the code:

Carte.h:

```
#ifndef CARTE_H_
#define CARTE_H_

class Carte
{
public:

    enum Sorte
    {
        coeur, pique, carreau, trefle
    };

    enum Valeur
    {
        as, valet, dame, roi
    };

                  Carte             (Sorte& pSorte, Valeur& pValeur);
    Sorte         lireSorte         () const;
    Valeur        lireValeur        () const;
    bool          ecrireSorte       (Sorte& pSorte);
    bool          ecrireValeur      (Valeur& pValeur);
    static bool   validerSorte      (const Sorte& pSorte);
    static bool   validerValeur     (const Valeur& pValeur);

private:

    Sorte  m_sorte;
    Valeur m_valeur;
};
#endif /* CARTE_H_ */
```

And here's the Carte.cpp:

```
#include "Carte.h"

using namespace std;

Carte::Carte(Sorte& pSorte, Valeur& pValeur)
{
    m_sorte = pSorte;
    m_valeur = pValeur;
};

Carte::Sorte const lireSorte()
{
    return m_sorte;
};

Valeur const lireValeur()
{
    return m_valeur;
};

bool ecrireSorte(Carte::Sorte& pSorte)
{
    bool donneeValide = validerSorte(pSorte);

    if (donneeValide)
    {
        m_sorte = pSorte;
    }

    return donneeValide;
};

bool ecrireValeur(Valeur& pValeur)
{
    bool donneeValide = validerValeur(pValeur);

    if (donneeValide)
    {
        m_valeur = pValeur;
    }

    return m_valeur;
};

static bool validerSorte(const Sorte& pSorte)
{
    return (pSorte == coeur || pSorte == pique || carreau || trefle);
};

static bool validerValeur(const Valeur& pValeur)
{
    return ((pValeur >= 2 && pValeur <= 10) || (pValeur == as || pValeur == valet || pValeur == dame || pValeur == roi));
};

#endif /* CARTE_H_ */
```

Everytime that I want to access the private enum(Sorte m_sorte and Valeur m_valeur) in my Carte.cpp, it gives me the following error:

> Symbol 'm_valeur' could not be resolved

or

> ‘carte’ was not declared in this scope

I have really no idea why it's telling me this, I included the .h file so isn't it supposed to know and be able to use my enum? I searched a lot on the internet, and I found people saying that I need to create an object. However, since my Carte.h and Carte.cpp are an object class, how can I create a Carte object my Carte class doesn't even compile?

Thanks and sorry again if I'm unclear!

Answer (score 2):

The methods in the `cpp` file are not specified as methods of a class. You need to specify the class name in their definition, e.g.:

```
Carte::Valeur Carte::lireValeur() const
```

Some of the returned enum types are not qualified with the class name either, eg. the one fixed in this example was not. Returned types need to be fully qualified becuase the scope of the method (the class they are in) is not yet known; or you can use the alternative function syntax where the return type is specified after the method name so the scope is known:

```
auto Carte::lireValeur() const -> Valeur
```

Also fixed in my example is that the `const` qualifier is for the method (so it comes after the method name), not the return type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Oops, I don't know what happened, but the #endif is in my .h file.

I specified the class like this "Valeur const Carte::lireValeur()" but now it says "Multiple markers at this line
 - Type 'Valeur' could not be resolved
 - Member declaration not found
 - ‘Valeur’ does not name a type"

Comment: @StenSoft Also the `enum` type needs to be qualified with scope, when used as a return value, as you've clarified in your sample (an explaining sentence would be nice).

Comment: Added explanation and fixed wrong position of `const` qualifier

Comment: Okay now it seems to work in the .cpp file, I added as you said the "Carte::Valeur Carte::lireValeur() const" and there's no more error, however, now it created another error in my .h file which I don't understand. Since I changed the method definition, I changed it in the header file too like that: "Carte::Valeur  Carte::lireValeur() const;" but now it says "extra qualification ‘Carte::’ on member ‘lireValeur’ [-fpermissive]". Do you know what I did wrong this time? Thanks a lot to both of you!

Comment: Don't change it in the h file, this definition matches the declaration you had there.

Comment: Yeah I just found why it doesn't work, I feel a bit dumb now. :P

It works, thanks a lot for your help :)